# Akka streaming 1.0-M4 missing classes after update

Tags: akka, akka-stream

I'm updating from

```
com.typesafe.akka:akka-stream-experimental_2.10:1.0-M3
```

to

```
com.typesafe.akka:akka-stream-experimental_2.10:1.0-M4
```

but there are no classes like UndefinedSource, UndefinedSink, BlackholeSink, SubscriberSink, OnCompleteSink and others.

There is no documentation why it was removed and which approach to be taken now instead of these classes.

Though in the documentation of this version I still see the notion of UndefinedSource

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0-M4/scala/stream-io.html

> The way we constructed a Flow using a PartialFlowGraph is explained in
>   detail in Constructing Sources, Sinks and Flows from Partial Graphs,
>   however the basic concepts is rather simple– we can encapsulate
>   arbitrarily complex logic within a Flow as long as it exposes the same
>   interface, which means exposing exactly one UndefinedSink and exactly
>   one UndefinedSource which will be connected to the TCP pipeline. In
>   this example we use a Concat graph processing stage to inject the
>   initial message, and then continue with handling all incoming data
>   using the echo handler. You should use this pattern of encapsulating
>   complex logic in Flows and attaching those to StreamIO in order to
>   implement your custom and possibly sophisticated TCP servers.

Seems to be that the documentation is wrong or some extra dependencies are required now

Comment: Check your "updated" from line. You have the same dependency before and after, you probably mean M3.

Comment: So it goes when working with an experimental api. Fwiw I think some of the concepts you mention have been moved to the Sink companion. Like Sink.ignore more or less is the BlackholeSink.

Comment: Looking at the source code, seems to be it is only one way how to migrate. Pity that no migration documentation or JavaDocs regarding it

Comment: Providing migration documentation for development snapshots would significantly slow us down, which I am very sure is not what you want ;-)